# Creating multi column indexes in MySQL that differ only in the rightmost (sorting) column

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, indexing

I've encountered a scenario in my app that I have been unable to find a good answer for regarding the use of multi column indexes.

I have a table Orders with columns

```
(id, merchant_id, section_id, status_id, created_date, invoice_date, shipped_date, ...<other data columns> )
```

id is the auto-incremented primary key.

I will be running queries of the form:

```
 SELECT id 
 FROM Orders 
 WHERE merchant_id=? 
    AND section_id=? 
    AND status_id=? 
 ORDER BY invoice_date LIMIT 25
```

The hierarchy of the ids is that merchant_id contains multiple section_ids, each section_id contains multiple status_ids, and each status_id contains a bunch of orders.  The user only ever sees orders in a specific merchant_id, section_id, status_id combination.  By default, the user sees orders sorted by invoice_date

This leads to the obvious index:

```
(merchant_id, section_id, status_id, invoice_date)
```

which will give me a covering index on the filtered columns as well as the sort.

However - the user is also allowed to change the sort order while viewing the page.  Thus, instead of the same query above sorted by invoice_date, it might instead be sorted by shipped_date or created_date.  It would still be constrained by the filters on merchant_id, section_id, and status_id.

Does this mean I would also need indexes on

```
(merchant_id, section_id, status_id, shipped_date)
```

as well as

```
(merchant_id, section_id, status_id, created_date)
```

If so, does MySQL in anyway take advantage of the fact that these indexes share the same 3 leftmost columns, or am I going to incur as much of a penalty as 3 distinct indexes on updates/inserts?

What about in terms of disk usage - are the 3 leftmost columns going to be duplicated for each of the indices?

Is there a better solution or approach to this type of scenario, where multiple indexes share some of the same leftmost columns?

Comment: Yes, composite keys are used in left->right ordering. If you have an index `(a,b,c,d,e)`, and your query involves `where a,b,d,e`, then the index can be used for fields `a,b`, but not `d,e` because you didn't include the `c` field.

Comment: I understand that, my question however is that if I have multiple composite indices that differ only in the rightmost column such as: (a,b,c,d) and (a,b,c,e), (a,b,c,f)  does mysql take advantage of the fact that these 3 indices share the same left heirarchy, or does it duplicate the data 3x.

Comment: ah. gotcha. no, it's 3 separate indexes entirely, with 3 separate data caches, and 3 separate updates if you change any of the indexed fields.

Comment: Basically, do I incur the same performance penalty on writes for the indices (a,b,c,d), (a,b,c,f), and (a,b,c,g) as I would if I had incompatible indexes such as (a,b,c,d), (b,d,c,a), and (c,d,b,a)?

Comment: Assumming that there is no `limit` clause, how many rows on average do these queries give ? Hundred, thousand, million ? If only a few dozen or hundred rows, then create only one index on leading three columns, and let MySql do a filesort. Indexing is a trade-off between disk space, queries time and updates time. More indexes - possible shorter queries time (but without any guarantee), but always more disk space and higher update time - and vice-versa.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that.  I am running my own tests right now with various index combinations to see what the actual performance tradeoff will be.  The index is a substantial performance increase on reads, as in some cases there can be as many as 100k rows in the result set (paginated via limit and offset), but it's hard to test the impact on write performance.  My goal with this question though was to figure out whether mysql does any sort of optimization when multiple indexes share left keys.  Based on the previous comment by @MarcB though, it seems that I incur the same overhead regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a index just over (merchant_id, section_id and status_id). This should be useful for all the different queries even with different `order by` conditions.